# Scrollbar in swt plus themeing

Tags: swt

I am trying to add a scroll bar to one of my composites but I am
having problems because when I add the scroll bar as follows:

```
final Composite first= new Composite(parent, SWT.BORDER);
first.setBounds(0, 0, 200, 100);
final StackLayout layout = new StackLayout();
first.setLayout(layout);
final Composite firstpg= new Composite(first, SWT.V_SCROLL);
```

it displays the scroll bar but the color that i have set using my
themeing will not work.
 but if i changed the last line to:

```
final Composite firstpg= new Composite(first, NONE);
```

my scroll bar isnt displayed but my themeing works perfectly.
Is there a way I can use themeing and display my scroll bar?

Regards
Ann

Comment: Can you add screenshots of the problem to your question..?